# Prevent jQuery slideDown() effect interfering with mouse scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a jQuery script to create a rapid sequence of slidedown effects:

```
$("#container > ul > li:gt(20)").remove();
$("#container").prepend(data);

$($(".item:hidden").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 200).slideDown(500);
});

$("#container > li:gt(19)").remove();
```

The only problem with this is it actually interferes sometimes with mouse scrolling. If you scroll down when the slideDown effect is taking place it sort of **grabs the user's window position and drags them down a bit too**.

This can be particularly annoying to users when they are trying to scroll up for example...

I have this "rapid fire" container in a column on the far left. I have more content that occupies most of the screen width in a larger column to the right.

This could possibly be caused by changes in the dimensions of the container. I tried limiting the size of the overall container div, but it had no effect.

Any of of you jQuery geniuses know how to fix this?

Comment: can you please  provide  full code ?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it in jsfiddle. Might take me some time though sorry.

Comment: I'd consider using CSS3 animations for this instead, where the DOM state won't be affected.